# plotting pie chart with reactjs and chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chartjs-2.6.0

i am trying to plot the pie chart using some dummy data. my react chart component looks like this:-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Bar,Line,Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData :props.chartData
        }
        console.log("props data ",props.chartData)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Pie 
            data={this.state.chartData}
            options={{
                title:'cool pie chart',
                text:"coolest data"
            }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

and i think the data passed on component is also absolutely fine.

[image]

but currently i can only plot the labels.
like this:-

[image]

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-chartjs` rather than `react-chartjs-2`. It works like a charm

Check the live demo here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p2bb24?embed=1&file=index.js